# Share WordPress login user detail to another application

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I want to Share WordPress current logged in user email to another application. How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the wordpress rest api https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/users/

and use http request from your application to access the data

Comment: how do i send current logged in user detail?if i manually put user id it works but when i used current logged in user function it return null.

Comment: it return null because it cant figure out which user to pull data from so u need to edit your wordpress login function to send the current login user id to a medium where u can access the id from your application to display the details ( cron job or firebase etc ... )

Comment: user activity plugin